# Spring MVC 3 Command Object values being lost between GET and POST operation

Tags: spring-mvc

My domain object does not keep the values that are not explicitly referenced in the JSP file between a GET and a POST operation on the same controller.  Here is a sample with error checking omitted

I have a domain object.

```
class foo
{
    private int fieldA;
    private String fieldB;
    // .. getters and setters omitted
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
@Autowired
private IDaoService daoService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/display", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newForm(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Model model, Principal principal) throws Exception
{
    // check that the user has permissions
    ...

    // get the object
    Foo foo = daoService.read(id);
    // at this point foo.fieldA is equal to the input id
    model.addAttribute("foo", foo);

    // return the JSP path
}

@RequestMapping(value="/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(@ModelAttribute("foo") Foo foo,
        BindingResult result, 
        Principal principal,
        Model model) throws Exception

{   
    // ERROR - at this point, fieldA is null

}
}
```

**JSP**

```
    <form:form  method="post" commandName="foo">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Invest</legend>
            <div class="fm-req">
                <label for="fm-name">Field B</label>    
                <spring:bind path="fieldB">
                    <input id="fm-name" type="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}" ></input>
                </spring:bind>
            </div>
            <div id="fm-submit" class="fm-req">
                <INPUT type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />        
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form:form>
```

I would have thought that the JSP gets the object created in newForm that has fieldA set ( and possibly fieldB ).  The user has the option to change fieldB and then hit submit.
I've done lots of reading of the Spring docs and checked web sites, but cannot find out why the foo.fieldA is null on the update method in the controller.

From what I understand about Spring MVC this appears to be a standard pattern, but please feel free to correct me.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If the model isn't in session, why would it?

Comment: I was under the assumption that the model input to newForm() is the model in the session as the JSP can access the command object.  Do I need to create a new model or how do I get the model that is in the session?  Thx

Comment: By default models live in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the expected behavior.

Both instances (in `newForm` and `update`) of the object `foo` *(in java class names should be start with upper case)* are complete independend of each other.

So eighter create a hidden field, or put it into the session.
I would recommend the hidden field:

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you would use the hidden field, rather than a session?  If the Foo(!) object has 20 fields, then wouldn't I have to define 20 hidden fields?

Comment: If the fiels are in the html files, then they are strongly attached to that form. -> No problem if the user uses different tabs or several browsers. And I do not need to spend time thinking about clearing not used stuff from the session. (Other reason is that the hidden fields put not so much load on the server) -- And I have the strong feeling that it is more clean to put every think that belongs to gether is in the same place (not spitet in html and session).

Comment: May our problem in an other one. -- May you should use different classes one for the domain entity and one special for the update form/command. This form/command-object should have only the fields that the form have.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one from following :

> 1. Use Ralph's way of hidden field.
> 2. Change type of Foo.fieldA to private Integer Foo

Reason May be: Foo.fieldA is creating problem because, NULL value is set to int type fieldA.