# How to preserve attributes of nested objects on thymeleaf forms

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I've got an object which I want to load the form fields for dynamically.  Instantiating and presenting the fields is working appropriately on display, however, when I attempt to submit the form, all of the data is lost except the `${field.value}` which is provided by the user.  How does one preserve all of the additional attribute values?

Here's the controller method that generates the form object:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newFooForm(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails user, @RequestParam("fooType") String fooType, @RequestParam("isTeam") Boolean isTeam, Model model) {
    Employee currentUser = getCurrentUser(user);
    List<FooFieldDefinition> fooFieldDefinitions = fooFieldDefinitionService.findByOrganizationalUnitIdAndIsTeam(currentUser.getOrgId(), isTeam);
    FooViewModel fooViewModel = new FooViewModel(currentUser, fooType, isTeam, fooFieldDefinitions);
    model.addAttribute("fooViewModel", fooViewModel);
    return "newFooForm";
}
```

The following snippet is called in the constructor `FooViewModel(currentUser, fooType, isTeam, fooFieldDefinitions)` which populates fooViewModel.fooFields:

```
fooFields = new ArrayList<>();
for (FooFieldDefinition fooFieldDefinition : fooFieldDefinitions) {
    fooFields.add(new FooField(fooFieldDefinition));
}
```

Here's the snippet of the form:

```
<form id="foo-form" action="#" th:action="@{/fooForms}" th:object="${fooViewModel}"
      method="post">
    <div th:each="fooField,iterationStatus  : *{fooFields}">
        <label th:text="${fooField.label}">Label</label>
        <input th:type="text" th:field="*{fooFields[__${iterationStatus.index}__].value}"/>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; right: 20px; bottom: 20px;">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" id="save" type="submit" name="save" value="Save"/>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

I know that the fooField has the appropriate data associated with the instance when the form is generated for 2 reasons.  The `label` prints, and through debugging, I can see that the instances have the appropriate data before the view name is returned in the`newFooForm` method.

Whenever I submit the form, all of the data for each `fooField` is set to null, except the value which is passed from the form.  I know this because, 1. The data is not preserved and 2. Debugging shows that.  Here's the controller method that's meant to hand the submission:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"save"})
public String fooFormDraftSubmit(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails user, @ModelAttribute FooViewModel fooViewModel, Model model) {
    Employee currentUser = getCurrentUser(user);
    Foo foo = new Foo(currentUser, fooViewModel);
    fooService.save(foo);
    for (FooField fooField : fooViewModel.getFooFields()) {
       fooFieldService.save(fooField);
    }
    FooViewModel persistedFooViewModel = new FooViewModel(foo);
    model.addAttribute("fooViewModel", persistedFooViewModel);
    return "fooView";
}
```

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out thanks to this post: [Spring MVC 3 Command Object values being lost between GET and POST operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743852/spring-mvc-3-command-object-values-being-lost-between-get-and-post-operation).  The suggestion specifically was to use a hidden field.  You have to access the attribute value of the `ViewModel` which is rendered on the page and assign it to the `ViewModel` that you wish to pass to the `POST` endpoint.

```
<form id="foo-form" action="#" th:action="@{/fooForms}" th:object="${fooViewModel}"
      method="post">
    <div th:each="fooField,iterationStatus  : *{fooFields}">
        <label th:text="${fooField.label}">Label</label>
        <input th:type="text" th:field="*{fooFields[__${iterationStatus.index}__].value}"/>
<!-- The fix, this is an example of 1 attribute.  Of course I will extend this for appropriate attribute values -->
        <input th:type="hidden" th:field="*{fooFields[__${iterationStatus.index}__].label}" th:value="${fooViewModel.fooFields[__${iterationStatus.index}__].label}"/>
<!-- End new code -->
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; right: 20px; bottom: 20px;">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" id="save" type="submit" name="save" value="Save"/>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```